# Request with Axios. How to solve the async problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have this `_id.vue` page on my Nuxt.js project:

```js
<template>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <HeaderApp>

      <DivHeaderMenu>
      </DivHeaderMenu>

    </HeaderApp>

    <CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp>
    </CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp>

    <FooterApp>
    </FooterApp>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
  //company_history
  import axios from 'axios';
  import HeaderApp from '~/components/HeaderApp';
  import FooterApp from '~/components/FooterApp';
  import CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp from '~/components/CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp'
  import DivHeaderMenu from '~/components/DivHeaderMenu';
  import Pixelperfect from '~/components/Pixelperfect';

  export default{

  async fetch ({ store, params, redirect, app}) {
    return axios.get('http://seo-gmbh.eu/json/api_sunds.php?action=get_pages&url=company_history')
    .then((res) => {
      store.commit('company_history/init_data_for_firmenistorie', res.data);
    })
  },


  async validate({store, params, redirect}) {

    const urlData = store.state.company_history.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieSortArrayData;
    let resultArray = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < urlData.length; i++) {
      if(params.id === urlData[i].toString()){
        return resultArray = urlData[i];
      }
    }

    if(resultArray == false){
        return redirect('/Firmenistorie');
    }
},


  head () {
    return {
      title: this.$store.state.company_history.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.meta.title,
      meta: [
        {description: this.$store.state.company_history.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.meta.description}
      ]
    }
  },

  components:{
    HeaderApp,
    FooterApp,
    CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp,
    DivHeaderMenu,
    Pixelperfect
  },


}

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

My task is to get a redirect when I get the 404th error on the dynamic page (_id). The whole implementation works fine if I go through nuxt-link (s) to similar pages - the 404th error works fine if I enter an incorrect URL in the address bar. But the problem appears if I'm already on a working page - I reload it. Instead of loading the same page again, I get the 404th error and redirect as a result. This happens because in this particular case I do not receive data from the store

My question is: How can I solve this (asynchronous, as I understand it) problem? (I tried everything that is possible - nothing helps).

My Vuex repository looks rather piled up - but just in case, I'll throw its code for a better understanding of the problem:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  dbFirmenstorie: {
    dbFirmenistorieData: null,
    dbFirmenistorieMaxYearData:  null,
    dbFirmenistorieMaxDetailsData:  null,
    dbFirmenistorieSortArrayData:  [],
  },
});

export const mutations = {

  init_data_for_firmenistorie (state, uploadDbFirmenistorieData) {

    state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData = uploadDbFirmenistorieData;
    state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.content_json = JSON.parse(state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.content_json);
    state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.meta = JSON.parse(state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.meta);

      for (let i = 0; i < state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.company_history_data.length; i++) {

        if(state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieSortArrayData.indexOf( Number( state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.company_history_data[i].company_history_from_year )) == -1 ){
          state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieSortArrayData.push(Number(state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.company_history_data[i].company_history_from_year));
        }

        if(state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieMaxYearData < Number(state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.company_history_data[i].company_history_from_year)){
          state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieMaxYearData = Number(state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.company_history_data[i].company_history_from_year);
          state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieMaxYearData = Number(state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.company_history_data[i].company_history_from_year);
          state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieMaxDetailsData = state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.company_history_data[i];
        }
      }

      function sortNumber(a, b) {
        return b - a;
      }

      state.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieSortArrayData.sort(sortNumber);


    }

};
```

Comment: Why are you including the Vue.js script tag? Nuxt should be including that for you. Also, there is no point to the `async` in `async fetch` if you're not taking advantage of `await` since you are returning a promise (which it expects in order to behave asynchronously).

Comment: What should I do - Do you have an idea of how to solve it a problem?

Comment: >> Why are you including the Vue.js script tag?
What do you mean?

Comment: (It does not have on my project - it just show into 'stack overflow' editor - because that don't have nuxt.js markdown as I see.)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that if you start using `catch()` with axios as everyone should always do, you will be able to handle all non 200 responses just fine. Which means 404, 40x, 50x, etc...

```
axios
.get("https://example.com")
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: http://joxi.ru/RmzB1JxTY1RKym
If I doing that - I have the same redirect after page reloading.